# How to return value of shell script to rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell

I have written a shell script which executing some of the mysql commands.

I want to run that shell script from rails side. And want to get result back  of commands to rails from shell script.

How may i handle it?

**EDIT:**

script.sh

```
mysql -u root -pmysql << eof
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table Name", table_rows AS "Quant of Rows", ROUND((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024,2) AS "Total Size Mb"  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema='database_name';
eof
```

This is my script. How may i return SELECT query result to rails ?

Comment: Hi, answer of Fareesh Vijayarangam is correct, you can use backticks, but since your "script" is in fact an sql query, I would suggest you running this query inside Rails, with ActiveRecord. Keep scripts when you need to link to command-line programs.

Comment: @plang How may i run this query from inside Rails ?

Comment: This is pure rails stuff: look at Active Record in your favorite documentation. Active Record is the Object Relational Mapper of Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, it will block until the script is finished and any output that it sent to standard out will be contained in the `output` variable.

```
output = `/my/script.sh`
puts output
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you tell me how may i pass SELECT query value to standard output ?

Comment: Since you are inside rails already, use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_query)` to run it directly, without the script.

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks   `       `

```
`/path/to/script` #backticks
```

**Edit**

To get the output of a mysql statement, use the `-e` flag

Eg. `mysql -e "SELECT * from information_schema"`

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you tell me how may i pass SELECT query value to standard output ?

Comment: I have pasted my script into root directory of my Rails Project.while trying to run shell script from console.>> \`show_table_size.sh\`
(irb):17: command not found: show_table_size.sh

Comment: You need to use `./file-name-of-script`. Also ensure that the interpreter directive (hashbang) is set at the first line of the shell script, eg. `#!/bin/sh`